# SQL Parameters Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

This would seem like an obvious typo with my parameter name, but I cannot spot it. Error message is:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@SelectedDepartment"

Code:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;

using (SqlConnection batConnection = new SqlConnection(batConstr))
{
    string actualsQuery = "SELECT * FROM Budget WHERE CostCenter = @SelectedDepartment AND Year = @SelectedYear";
    
    using (SqlCommand actualsCommand = new SqlCommand(actualsQuery, batConnection))
    {
        actualsCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        actualsCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedDepartment", budgetsActuals.SelectedDepartment);
        actualsCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedYear", Convert.ToInt32(budgetsActuals.SelectedYear));
    
        batConnection.Open();
        ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(batConnection, CommandType.Text, actualsQuery);
    }
}
```

I have debugged the code and can confirm the DB connection is good and the model has the values to populate the parameters. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset` but I don't see you using the SqlCommand in the call to it.

Comment: i guess you should pass parameters of the query into ExecuteDataset method. If i am not mistaken it should have one more parameter. also.

Comment: We don't know what `SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset` does. I would assume its a static function from the looks of it. Currently it's not helping you at all, your constructing the connection, the command etc. Honestly at this point, you can get rid of that call and just use a `DataAdapter` and fill the `DataSet`. On the other hand, I would create a helper function in your class (maybe `Budget`) that utilizes the `SqlHelper` class to make such calls and return the data you need. Also your connections should be disposed of as well when done.

Comment: One more suggestion, don't use `AddWithValue`, use `Add` and specify the datatype, length etc. of the parameter. If you don't it will infer the data type and that could be wrong. Also, could you be using `Microsoft Data Access Application Block`?

Comment: Finally, your query is already in the command object, you shouldn't have to pass this in that function. It may be something similar to: `SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet(batConnection, actualsCommand);`

Comment: use dapper, everything is easier there and the execution speed is good :)

Comment: `ExecuteDataset(batConnection, CommandType.Text` <-- this passes the SQL to the ExecuteDataset method, but not the associated parameters. Find a different overload, or a different way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks @LasseV.Karlsen. I think that's the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

LasseV.Karlsen was correct in the comments; the parameters were not being passed to the ExecuteDataset(...) method. This is what worked for me:

```
using (SqlConnection batConnection = new SqlConnection(batConstr))
{
    string actualsQuery = "SELECT * FROM Budget WHERE CostCenter = 
        @SelectedDepartment AND Year = @SelectedYear";
    
    using (SqlCommand actualsCommand = new SqlCommand(actualsQuery, batConnection))
    {
        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[2];
        parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@SelectedDepartment",
            budgetsActuals.SelectedDepartment);
        parameters[0].Value = budgetsActuals.SelectedDepartment;
        parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@SelectedYear",
            budgetsActuals.SelectedYear);
        parameters[1].Value = budgetsActuals.SelectedYear;

        batConnection.Open();
        ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(batConstr, CommandType.Text, actualsQuery,
            parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nuance of ADO.NET is that if the value of a parameter is `null`, the parameter **is not added** (for input purposes, at least). As such, when adding - you should check for `null` and use `DbNull.Value` instead.